# Removing navigation back arrow in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. I would like to remove/hide the back arrow in my navigation bars but keep the title. I was able to do it in iOS using the following code inside my `NavigationPageRenderer`:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackIndicatorImage = new UIImage();
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = new UIImage();
```

Is there any equivalent code for this in Android that I could use inside my renderer or in the MainActivity? I tried `this.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` inside my `MainActivity` but the `ActionBar` always returns null. Below is my my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
       TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
       ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

       base.OnCreate(bundle);

       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
       LoadApplication(new App());
       if (Window != null)
       {
          Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
       }

       this.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

     }
}
```

What I want my navigation bar to look like something like the image below (this is in my iOS app).

[image]

The back arrow is just the back button title: `NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "\u25C3");`

In my `ContentPage`:

```
public partial class HomeTabPage : ContentPage
{
   public HomeTabViewModel vm;

   public HomeTabPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingContext = vm = new HomeTabViewModel(this);
      NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
      NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "\u25C3");
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be something like `Page.HasBackButton = false`. You may have to cast this: `ViewController.ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(!((CustomContentPage)this.Element).HasBackButton, false);`

Comment: If you meant `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);` then yeah I tried that but not working

Comment: Which page did you use when you called NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false)?  If you set it on the NavigationPage, it won't do anything.

Comment: Can you provide the effect screenshot that you want ? NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); should works if you call it in contentPage.

Comment: I did call it in my ContentPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
You can define a custom view as navigationBar of your content on specific platform (Android).Refer to the following code.

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        if(Device.RuntimePlatform=="Android")
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, SetBackView("Title", "back"));
        }


    }

    private void BackButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    StackLayout SetBackView (string title,string backButtonContent)
    {
        Button backButton = new Button()
        {

            Text = backButtonContent,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontAttributes=FontAttributes.None,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            Margin = new Thickness(-20,0,0,0),
        };
        backButton.Clicked += BackButton_Clicked;

        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {

            Children = {

                backButton,

                new Label{

                    HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text=title,
                    TextColor=Color.White,
                    BackgroundColor=Color.Transparent,
                },

            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        return stackLayout;
    }

}
```

And the effect is just like the following ,you can set the content of page title and `backButton` as you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and will get back to you in a while.

Comment: Tried it on a test project and it seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Happy coding :)